# Can clients find php code inside html files?

Tags: php, html, client

I know they can't if it's a .php file but if it is in  tags inside a .html file?
I couldn't find any info on this on google so I had to ask here.

Comment: if apache is configured to send html files to php: no

Comment: Post a sample of what you mean. The answer is no if you mean something like `<h1><?php echo 'hi';?></h1>`. This will display as `<h1>hi</h1>`. If PHP is installed, functioning correctly, and the file is `.php`/ or handler has been modified to serve requested extension.

Comment: PHP is a _preprocessor_ which essentially means that the HTML or PHP files are being _processed prior_ to being shown to the user. If PHP works on your server, then PHP code is not visible to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As people have stated in the comments they cannot see your code as long as the server is configured correctly.

However, many web servers will eventually have their configuration files edited which from time to time will cause an error that would leave your code visible until fixed. If you have somewhat sensitive material in your PHP code (such as an API key) then you might consider issues such as the following:

- Store sensitive code in an area that your web server won't provide direct access to.
- Use an appropriate include method to get access to sensitive code without putting it directly into a web page.